# Add syntax highlighting for the Makefile language

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

I want to post a question with a significant chunk of Makefile code, but the preview given from my code isn't very exciting, and it highlights seemingly random words here and there.

The seemingly-authoritative [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) doesn't list Makefile as a supported language, but https://github.com/google/code-prettify does.  There is an existing makefile tag.  Is it possible to add support for the Makefile language to the Stack Exchange servers' instance of Google Code Prettify?

Comment: are you sure there is a specific prettifier for Make - files? Because I can't find an explicit implementation for that in the GitHub repo. Did you try, surrounded by empty lines, this `<!-- language: lang-default -->` before your code block  to see how it looks?

Comment: What tags did your question have?

Answer (score 4):

Now that Stack Exchange moved to [Highlight.js](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter) lang-makefile is definitely supported (it might already have been supported on prettify earlier but I didn't intend to make this answer an accurate historical recollection of facts).

And here is an example makefile, taken from the [answer on What is the purpose of .PHONY in a Makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2145605/578411) from user [Eli Bendersky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8206/eli-bendersky)

```makefile
.PHONY: clean
clean:
  rm -rf *.o
```

This is the markup of above snippet:

````
    ```lang-makefile
    .PHONY: clean
    clean:
      rm -rf *.o
    ```
````

Comment: I can confirm that makefile is present in the highlight-loader.js file on the dev CDN.