# Syntax highlighting of Makefiles

Tags: bug, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

The syntax highlighting is bugged for [Makefiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)#Makefiles).

- As per https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/356459/1288919 I used:

  ````
  ```lang-makefile
  ````
- Current output for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77223358/22510042

  [image: Current output]
- Same code as rendered in the [Kate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kate_%28text_editor%29) editor:

  [image: Output in Kate]

---

Highlight.js bug report: *[(makefile) Syntax highlighting of Makefiles #3878](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues/3878)*

Answer (score 7):

That is a bug in Highlight.JS, not in the software that SE has control over.  You need to file the bug [in the issue tracker of Highlight.js](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues) and then wait for them to fix it in a release before SE can upgrade their version.

See the [demo](https://highlightjs.org/demo#lang=makefile&v=1&theme=atom-one-dark&code=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%2BY29tbWFuZCAtdiDHJSAyPiAvZGV2L251bGzGMgkkKGV2YWwgxQwJyDvGDgnqAWxcdDo9XHQlc1xuIsgdCSQoY2FsbCDnATXoAIkgKcsh%2FwCJ5wCJxjDGB8YGLCQoZXJyb3IgTm8gJ8c0JyBpbiBQQVRIxSPEBcQE5wKY9gCMKeUCTtccKSlcCuQCuVRoZXJlIGlzIGEgXHQgY2hhciBiZeQBjSB0aGUgPcR2xAnFZ2zkAuNhYm92ZSBmb3IgYWxpZ25tZW50Li4u7AMiRU5E7wMgxx0pICMgRW1wdHnFSgojIOgA6MUyRm9yY2VkKQo%3D) or this screenshot for comparison:

[image]

The highlighter breaks when you nest a `$()` inside an another `$()` like you do here `$(shell string="$(strip $1)"; printf "%s" $${string^^})`

Comment: Thanks! I'd wondered whether this was the case and I'm glad you're able to confirm. I'm not sure whether we'll update automatically but if it gets fixed, we can make sure it does.

Comment: Filed bug report, link is at bottom of OP.